# NetLogo GIS: dealing with large shapefile

Tags: gis, netlogo, shapefile, overhead

I'm developing a NetLogo model using the GIS extension to import a road network shapefile. The model works fine when I work on a small area of about 5x5 km. However I would like to allow potential users of the model to determine themselve their area/extent of interest. For this aim, I have to load the complete road shapefile which is very large (> 2GB) since it covers a whole country area. 
My idea was to import this shapefile and to use user-defined parameters (using "input" buttons) to set the envelop of the world. Of course I'm facing "GC overhead limit" issue when importing the large shapefile...

I was wondering whether anybody would have a suggestion to deal with this question. I thought about the R extension to send a command to R for cutting the area of interest and sending the subarea back to NetLogo, but I'm not sure whether the extension is really made for this.

Thanks for your help,

Kevin

Answer (score 0):

I think the R or Python extension would work well for this.

```
r:put "minX" extent_minX
r:put "minY" extent_minY
r:put "maxX" extent_maxX
r:put "maxY" extent_maxY

;Write a little function that takes the coordinates and returns the path to the clipped vector.
r:eval "PathVector = ClipFunction(minX, minY, maxX, maxY)"

set PathToVector r:get "PathVector"

;load the dataset. Something like
set roads gis:load-dataset PathToVector
gis:set-world-envelope (gis:envelope-of roads)
;etc. I've only ever loaded rasters, not vector, but you have this code.
```

Then either immediately, or at the end of run, you'll need to delete the vector file.

```
r:eval "deletefile(PathVector)
```